# webDriver.switchTo().alert().dismiss() is not working in Selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, dialog

I am trying to join zoom meeting from browser using [selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) but I am not able to click on Confirmation Dialog to not open meeting in Zoom Desktop app.

[image]

```js
require('chromedriver');
const { Builder, Browser, By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

const delay = (ms) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    try {
        await driver.get('https://us04web.zoom.us/j/74468563733?pwd=tdvfpLvoL_ktFwO-5reV36kjicgBBx.1');
        delay(5000)
        await driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss()
    } finally {
        // await driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

What I am missing to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes using that can occur some problems. I experienced the same stuff in the .NET either.

I solved the problem by using SendKeys method. I sent 3-4 times tab key and after doing that I sent an enter key.

It is not the best solution but you can try it.

Here's the C# code, you can convert it to JS:

```
firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Tab);
firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//body")).SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Enter);
```